# Saving value from textfield as I move through viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm setting up a user registration form with multiple view controllers. When the user enters in their username, and clicks a button, it will segue to the next view controller with email information and when they hit a button it will segue to the next view. When I get to the last view however, I want to be able to have all of the information available to me. I don't want to display it to the user, but I want to be able to collectively send it to my database. Is there a good way of saving this information in an array without having to make the textfield variables public?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let DestViewController : AddComDescriptionVC = segue.destination as! AddComDescriptionVC

        DestViewController.comNameLblTxt = comNameTxt.text!

    }
```

For example this is me passing data to the next view. I dont want to store it in a label like I've done. I just want to pass the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a variable in each of your view controllers, and keep passing them until the point that you need to send it to the data base. Since you are just setting value for this variable (property), user will not see it from the screen. For example, to pass data though segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? YourViewController {

        destinationViewController.texts = self.texts
        //...
    }
}
```

If you only need it at the beginning and in the end, and do not want to pass it though all the view controllers in the middle, save it into `UserDefault` from the first view controller, and then read the value whenever you want to send it to your database

To simply save and read a string from user default, use the following code

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(yourTextField.text!, forKey: "savedText")

UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedText")
```

Comment: can you please provide sample code, sorry i'm very new to swift.

Comment: @codeislife Updated segue code. In your code, you are casting the destination view controller to your desired view controller. However this may cause casting exceptions. Instead, use `if let` to first test if the destination view controller is what you want, and then pass data.

Comment: Should I store the userdefaults inside the prepare for segue function?

Comment: @codeislife You can do that wherever that you have the value to be saved. It does not have to be in prepare for segue function. It will save the string as part of your app and you can even read from that string after close and reopen your app